# string is not behaving as HTML

Tags: php, html

```
$str = '&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;Important: Nu Ã®ncÄƒrcaÅ£i orice fotografie care poate fi interpretatÄƒ ca o obscenitate, material protejat de Copyright, hÄƒrÅ£uire sau spam.&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;';
echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

browser output:

```
<strong>Important: Nu Ã®ncÄƒrcaÅ£i orice fotografie care poate fi interpretatÄƒ ca o obscenitate, material protejat de Copyright, hÄƒrÅ£uire sau spam.</strong>
```

I want it to behave as html means browser should show strong.

Comment: Wow... uhm... you have *serious* encoding issues there. Not only is your HTML *double* encoded, your text encoding is also messed up. You should try to fix this at the root somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html_entity_decode replaces all '<' before it comes to the '&', thus resulting in not finding any '<' and simply decoding '&' to '&'.
Pulling it through html_entity_decode again or making sure that '&' is not encoded in the string (displaying like '&') can solve it.

```
//current situations:
echo html_entity_decode('&amp;lt;); //'&lt;'

//possible solutions:
echo html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode('&amp;lt;)); //'<'
echo html_entity_decode('&lt;); //'<'
```

Comment: Thanx alot. it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Removing that `amp;` part, you should use this:

```
$str = '&lt;strong&gt;';
echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

Answer (score -1):

browser displays special characters due to encode issue

use utf-8

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php